# VB.NET - Pass command on command line

Tags: .net, vb.net, scheduled-tasks

I am struggling to pass a parameter to a VB.NET application via a Windows scheduled task.  It works perfectly in Visual Studio (passing a command line arguement via project properties).

If I am calling a VB6 application, then I will supply the following parameters and it works:

Run: c:\progra~1\Test\Test.exe TestParameter
Start In: c:\progra~1\Test\

However, if I supply the same parameters in VB.NET, the program throws an exception when it tries to create an instance of a class in the Form.Load: System.NullReferenceException cannot create instance of object.

I have also tried the following:

Run: c:\program files\Test\Test.exe TestParameter
Start In: "c:\program files\Test\"

This time the status of the scheduled task changes to "cannot start".

What is the correct way to specify command line parameters in a scheduled task for a VB.NET program?

UPDATE
I found the solution on this web page: http://forum.codecall.net/topic/47568-reading-command-line-arguments-in-vbnet/.  I am still confused as to why the program would not create an instance of an object when I used the 8 bit paths (i.e. progra~1)

Comment: What is the line of code in `Form.Load` that is throwing the exception?

Comment: objectUser=New classUser

Comment: this is getting parsed c:\program files\Test\Test.exe  you need quotes around it "c:\program files\Test\Test.exe"

Comment: @Blam, thanks.  What difference does the quotes make?

Comment: the space in c:\program files\Test\Test.exe is getting parsed so files\Test\Text.exe is treated as a parameter

Comment: @Blam, thanks (+1).  What is the difference between using quotes and specifying the path like this: progra~1.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be interested to see the code in the constructor (or the Form_Load event) where you're getting the null reference exception. The difference between progra~1 and "program files" might depend on what's in there.

Comment: ,thanks.  The constructor has no arguements.  It is not overloaded.